# passing props to bundled vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, bundle, rollup, vue-props

I created a bundled **myproject.min.js** file using rollup, now I am using this in other frameworks(aurelia and angular).

Now my concern is how to pass data as props to this vue bundle from other frameworks:

in script file:

```
Vue.use(window.VueMainComponent);
new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

in HTML file:

```
<div id="app">
        <vue-main-component :data="somedata"></vue-main-component>
    </div>
```

I am trying above approach, but obviously getting the error **somedata** is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured this out, I made use of Vue.prototype.

in script file:

```
Vue.prototype.$somedata = {};
Vue.use(window.VueMainComponent);
new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

in HTML file:

```
 <div id="app">
        <vue-main-component :data="$somedata"></vue-main-component>
 </div>
```